# Pass sp_linkedserver parameters from SSRS into SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, mdx, linked-server

I'am trying to combine SQL and MDX data on SQL Server Reporting Services.

I found a solution about the `sp_addlinkedserver`.

```
Exec sp_addlinkserver
   @server = 'localhost'
   @srvproduct = ''
   @provider = 'MSOLAP'
   @datasrc = 'localhost\instancename'
   @catalog = 'Databasename'
```

My problem in the above code was that the value of `@server, @datasrc` and `@catalog` is dynamic. Sometimes, SQL Server database and Olap cube are on a different machines and different instance names based on the choice of a customer how it will be deployed.

I want to create an SSRS report where it can pass the parameter for the `@server, @datasrc` and `@catalog` based on the "SSRS datasource" it is using. This parameters will be forwarded on the SQL Server stored procedure which will somewhat look like the code below

```
Exec sp_addlinkserver
  @server = @servername_of_the_olap_database
  @srvproduct = ''
  @provider = 'MSOLAP'
  @datasrc = @datasource_of_the_olap_database
  @catalog = @olap_database
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! THat way, you don't need any of those messy `<br>` tags, either!

Comment: thanks marc_s, I will be doing that next time :)